# How to search the underscore in a column for SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to search for the underscore in a column for SQL?

I tried:

`select * from xxx where xxx like '%_%';`
and
`select * from xxx where xxx like '%$_%';`

But that doesn't work as expected. How do I escape underscore in SQL LIKE Operator?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I used the Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE xxx LIKE '%[_]d'
```